# Represent query from Stored Procedure that return multiple Tables in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used below stored procedure.

```
 DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetAllUser`()
 BEGIN

 Select userId, userName, userEmail, userFirstName, userLastName from usertbl order by userId ASC;

 Select count(*) as total from usertbl ;

 END
```

I know how to execute this procedure. For this purpose I have used below function that return result. but how to differentiate and print two tables(one is user table and other represent total) return from stored procedure.

```
function GetAllUser() {
    $query = "CALL GetAllUser()";
    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
      $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);
      return $query_run;
    }
    else {
      return '0';
    }
```

}

Sorry, for Bad English.

Comment: Only use the first select in your stored procedure. The second value is the total amount of rows your first select returns. And why are you using stored procedures for this?

Comment: this is not my original stored procedure. I have use stored procedure for the purpose of managing pagination. so in first select that return user list and second select return my current page. Can apply .Net C# DataSet like concept in php?